# How to use *ngIf to get value in slide IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m using *ngIf in Slides to get all values of id_qtype in slides

id_qtype parameter have 5 values are:

```
id_qtype = 1;
id_qtype = 2;
id_qtype = 3;
id_qtype = 4;
id_qtype = 5;
```

When I use *ngIf as below, it seem get data incorrect

This my sources:

**HTML**:

```
<ion-slides>             
<ion-slide *ngFor="let myValue of item; let i = index;">
<div *ngIf="myValue.id_qtype =='1'>     <!-- ;else elsetag" -->
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding class="mark_answer_inside">
        <ion-label>① <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex1"></div></ion-label>                                
    </ion-item>                           
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding>
        <ion-label>② <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex2"></div> </ion-label>                  
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>

<div *ngIf="myValue.id_qtype =='2'>     
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding class="mark_answer_inside">
        <ion-label>① <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex1"></div></ion-label>                                
    </ion-item>                           
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding>
        <ion-label>② <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex2"></div> </ion-label>                  
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>

<div *ngIf="myValue.id_qtype =='3'>     
<ion-list radio-group>      
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding>
        <ion-label>② <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex2"></div> </ion-label>                  
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>

<div *ngIf="myValue.id_qtype =='4'>     
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding class="mark_answer_inside">
        <ion-label>① <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex1"></div></ion-label>                                
    </ion-item>                           
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding>
        <ion-label>② <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex2"></div> </ion-label>                  
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>

<div *ngIf="myValue.id_qtype =='5'>     
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-item no-lines no-padding class="mark_answer_inside">
        <ion-label>① <div class="mark_answer" [innerHTML]= "myValue.ex1"></div></ion-label>                                
    </ion-item>                                 
</ion-list>
</div>
<ion-slides>
</ion-slide>
```

How to get correct value when id_qtype = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 in slides ?

Comment: your `ion-slides` container doesnt seem to have `ion-slide` and also your first `ngIf` has `myValue.id_qtype` and others have `etest.id_qtype`. Please check your code again...

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: I have updated code yet

Comment: you can use ngSwitch with string value in your type will help you on above case.

Comment: @CodeChanger: Do you have a example about using ngSwitch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngSwitch` like below code :

```
<div [(ngSwitch)]="caseView" class="content-div-style">
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'1'">
</ion-list>
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'2'">
</ion-list>
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'3'">
</ion-list>
</div>
```

Based on above code you can use `ngSwitch` with different different case.